# Adding new constructors to a specialised template class

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, partial-specialization

I have a class defining an array of fixed length `n`, with some methods.

```
template<int n>
struct array_container{
    /* some code here */
   int array[n];
};
```

Let's say I want to add a constructor to `array_container<3>`, something along the lines of:

```
array_container<3>::array_container(int a0, int a1 ,int a2){
     array[0] = a0; 
     array[1] = a1; 
     array[2] = a1; 
}
```

I know of two ways to do this:

One is to copy the entire code of the generic class, replacing `n` with 3, and add my constructor:

```
template<>
struct array_container<3>{
   /* some code here */
   int array[3];
   
  array_container(int a0, int a1 ,int a2){
     array[0] = a0; 
     array[1] = a1; 
     array[2] = a1; }
};
```

This works correctly, but has the disadvantage of needing to copy all the code and methods from the generic base.

Another method is to add a constructor  `array_container(int a0, int a1, int a2);` in the generic class, then define:

```
template<>
array_container<3>::  array_container(int a0, int a1 ,int a2){
     array[0] = a0; 
     array[1] = a1; 
     array[2] = a1; }
```

This has the disadvantage of populating my generic base class with at best undefined or at worst incorrect constructors, such as
`array_container<2>(int a0, int a1 ,int a2)` (undefined or incorrect depending on whether or not I add the definition to the generic base or not).

Is there any approach that avoids both pitfalls? Ie. doesn't need to copy-paste the entire generic base code for the specialization, and doesn't add unnecessary constructors to the generic base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any approach that avoids both pitfalls? Ie. doesn't need to copy-paste the entire generic base code for the specialization, and doesn't add unnecessary constructors to the generic base?

Ignoring the fact that, as @Goswin von Brederlow mentions, you seem to be reinventing the wheel (`std::array` and aggregate initialization), C++20's requires-expressions allows you to define constructors in a primary template that are constrained to only certain specializations. E.g.:

```
#include <type_traits>

// Helper trait for constraining a ctor to a set
// of specializations.
template <int n, int... ns> struct is_one_of {
  static constexpr bool value{false};
};

template <int n, int n0, int... ns> struct is_one_of<n, n0, ns...> {
  static constexpr bool value{(n == n0) || is_one_of<n, ns...>::value};
};

template <int n, int... ns>
inline constexpr bool is_one_of_v{is_one_of<n, ns...>::value};

template <int n> struct array_container {
  /* some code here */
  int array[n];

  // Constrained to n == 3 or n == 5.
  template <typename... Args>
      requires(std::is_same_v<Args, int> &&...) && (sizeof...(Args) == n) &&
      is_one_of_v<n, 3, 5 /*, ... */> array_container(Args... args)
      : array{args...} {}
};

// Demo.
array_container<3> arr3{1, 2, 3};       // OK
array_container<4> arr4{1, 2, 3, 4};    // Error (no matching ctor)
array_container<5> arr5{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // OK
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had a different structure in mind as argument for the constructor (one that only makes sense to get cast as an array of size 6, no other size), but the answers seem to be focusing on variadic initialization.

Comment: @user3257842 The same technique (define the ctor(s) in the primary template and constrain them to certain or a single specialization) applies likewise to that use case; the variadic init is a red herring here, representing just an example (based on your own example). One of the neatest things with requires-expressions applied on member functions is that the member functions needn't be template functions: you can likewise constrain non-template member functions of a class template (e.g. based on traits on the template parameter(s) of the class template).

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use

```
template <std::size_t size>
struct MyArrayWithFunctions : std::array<int, size> {
    /* some functions */
};
```

`std::array` allows aggregate initialization and even deduces the size so you can simply write

```
MyArrayWithFunctions arr{1,2,3};
```

You can add a deduction guideline for your own class but why re-implement `array`?

Comment: Note that you can still store the array as a `std::array` member function, and then add a constructor that passes any arguments to the constructor of that array.

Comment: @G.Sliepen But then you don't have aggregate initialization anymore and have to implement a constructor with initializer list to do basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution would be to construct it with an array(in place).

```
template<int n>
struct array_container{
    int array[n];
    
    array_container(std::array<int, n> arrayIn)
    {
        std::copy(arrayIn.begin(), arrayIn.end(), array); 
    }
};
```

Otherwise you can mess with variadic templates and parameter unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

If happen to have a C++17 compiler you can use the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

// class definition
template<int n>
struct array_container {
    int array[n];

    template<typename... Args, typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<int, Args> && ...) && (sizeof...(Args) == n), bool> = true>
    array_container(Args... args):
        array{args...}
    {}
};

// user defined template deduction guide
template<typename... Args>
array_container(Args...) -> array_container<sizeof...(Args)>;
```

and use it like

```
array_container<3> x {1,2,3};
```

or even let the size be deduced from the number of arguments like

```
// n deduced to 3 from the number of arguments
array_container x {1,2,3};
```

The constructor is a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), taking any number of `int` arguments (the latter is enforced by the `std::enable_if_t` template parameter) and initializes the `array` member from them. A [user defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) can be used to automatically deduce the `n` parameter from the number of arguments, that you pass to the constructor.

See it live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y33jKbPd1).